# При change select в val() показывает уже выбранное значение, а как взять старое?

Tags: jquery, события

При

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
  var val = $(this).val(); // Показывает значение выбранное сейчас
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="name">
      <option value="1" selected>Мото</selected>
      <option value="2">Авто</selected>
    </select>
```

А если у меня быо выбрано: "мото" до выбора, как это определить в рамках события change?

Comment: записывать старое значение в отдельную переменную

Comment: @Cheg а через события никак это не отловить?

Comment: через событие и записывать

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуемся событием `focus` для первого сохранения и далее просто обновляем:

```js
(function(){
    let previous;

    $("select").on('focus', e => previous = e.target.value).change(e => {
        // Прошлое значение value
        console.info(previous);

        // Необходимо обновить, иначе последующие смены не будут работать
        previous = e.target.value;
    });
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="name">
  <option value="1" selected>Мото</option>
  <option value="2">Авто</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
    $('select').each(function() {
        $(this).data('old_val', $(this).val());
    });
    $('select').on('change', function() {
        var old = $(this).data('old_val'); // Старое значение берём
        var val = $(this).val(); // Показывает значение выбранное сейчас
        alert('Было ' + old + ' стало ' + val);
        // ......
        $(this).data('old_val', $(this).val()); // Старое значение обновляем
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="name">
      <option value="1" selected>Мото</selected>
      <option value="2">Авто</selected>
    </select>
```